# Failed to start SonarQube in Windows Subsystem (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: sonarqube, ubuntu-16.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

**I'm using windows 10 with Ubuntu sub system.I've tried to start server using**

```
/opt/sonar/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start
```

But getting error

```
Starting SonarQube...
Failed to start SonarQube.
```

**And no logs being generated.**i want to know how can i run sonarqube perfectly in WSL without using root. I know we can’t run sonarqube as root but when I try to start the server using superuser then its being started but sonar not working.

Error Logs:

```
2018.02.21 07:26:59 ERROR es[][o.e.b.Bootstrap] Exception
java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) [elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
2018.02.21 07:26:59 WARN  es[][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:123) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:70) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:134) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:91) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:84) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: can not run elasticsearch as root
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initializeNatives(Bootstrap.java:106) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:195) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:132) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]
        ... 6 more
```

Sonar Logs:

```
Launching a JVM...
Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org
  Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.

2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory /opt/sonar/temp
2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.es.EsSettings] Elasticsearch listening on /127.0.0.1:9001
2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.p.ProcessLauncherImpl] Launch process[[key='es', ipcIndex=1, logFilenamePrefix=es]] from [/opt/sonar/elasticsearch]: /opt/sonar/elasticsearch/bin/elasticsearch -Epath.conf=/opt/sonar/temp/conf/es
2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Waiting for Elasticsearch to be up and running
2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2018.02.21 07:26:50 INFO  app[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2018.02.21 07:26:59 WARN  app[][o.s.a.p.AbstractProcessMonitor] Process exited with exit value [es]: 1
2018.02.21 07:26:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] Process [es] is stopped
2018.02.21 07:26:59 INFO  app[][o.s.a.SchedulerImpl] SonarQube is stopped
<-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Comment: Could be problems with the file restrictions. Does the user have the rights to run the application and write logs? Also why do you use the linux subsystem. We use Sonarqube on a windows server and it runs just fine.

Comment: Dear @Fabrice - SonarSource Team you must need to read complete question

Comment: @DipendraSharma Sorry, because of the huge stacktrace related to the usage of root, I missed the point. I suggest that you edit your question to remove that part (about launching as "root") since it hides the real question.

Comment: Can you please edit this if you can....

Comment: @Ssindeler, i checked many blog. And tried to provide complete permission but not able to run still.

Comment: @DipendraSharma On our side, we can't really help you because this setup is quite unusual so we've never tested it. Why are you trying to run SonarQube on the Ubuntu-based subsystem in the first place? Why not simply running it directly on Windows?

Comment: @Fabrice - SonarSource Team Well, I think if you have 10 min to install a SonarQube on WSL, it would be useful because I can confirm it doesn't start for an unclear reason. The "why a linux sonarqube server instead of windows sonarqube server" is out of scope I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sonarqube has docker server configuration requirements. Same as in the document description.

> Because SonarQube uses an embedded Elasticsearch, make sure that your
> Docker host configuration complies with the Elasticsearch production
> mode requirements and File Descriptors configuration.
>
> For example, on Linux, you can set the recommended values for the
> current session by running the following commands as root on the host:
>
> ```
> sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
> sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072
> ulimit -n 131072
> ulimit -u 8192
> ```

For windows with docker wsl, I have configured

```
wsl -d docker-desktop
sysctl -w vm.max_map_count=524288
sysctl -w fs.file-max=131072
ulimit -n 131072
```

And it seems to have worked correctly.
Hope this helps you.